# Show $P(D-C) \geq ((P(A)-P(B) + P(D)-P(C)) $

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $ (A-B)\subset (C-D)$ then $P(D-C) \geq ((P(A)-P(B))+(P(D)-P(C))$

I'm supposed to use set operations and the definition or properties of the probability function but I'm not really sure how to begin. Is the statement telling me that $(A-B) \cup (D-C)$ is a subset of $D-C$? Please let me know how I could begin this proof.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: $P(C)+P(D-C)=P(D)+P(C-D)$. [Split $C$ into $C\cap D$ and $C-D$ then  $D$ into $D\cap C$ and $D-C$ to prove this].

Step 2: $P(A)-P(B) \leq P(A-B)$. [This easy].

Combine Step 1 and Step 2 (and the fact that $P(A-B) \leq P(C-D)$) to finish the proof.

[$P(D-C)=P(D)+P(C-D)-P(C)$ by Step 1. So $P(D-C)=P(D)+P(C-D)-P(C)\geq P(D)+P(A-B)-P(C)$ (because $A-B \subset C-D$). By Step 3 we get $P(D-C) \geq  P(D)+P(A)-P(B)-P(C)$ which is exactly what you are asked to prove.]

Comment: What does Step 1 tell me about $P(D-C)$ and $P(D)-P(C)$? Do I also have to show $P(D)-P(C) \leq P(D-C)$ in step 2? Sorry, I'm just really having trouble comprehending the problem